# How to work out which frameworks are triggering privacy-sensitive .plist issues

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

I've got the classic problem of iTunes rejecting my .ipa because it's missing a bunch of .plist entries for 'privacy-senstive data' (in my case calendar, contacts, microphone, Apple Music and Siri!), despite my app having nothing to do with these frameworks.

I want to work out which 3rd party frameworks in my app are triggering this problem, rather than take the easy way out and just add the .plist entries.

Is there a way to analyse your .ipa or the files it contains to work out which 3rd party dependency is causing this issue?

Just to be clear, I understand I could just add the required .plist entries and this problem would go away - my question is specifically how to work out which dependencies are triggering this problem.

Comment: Is your `Link Behavior` in your release configuration set to `Don't Link`?

Comment: Good question @SushiHangover - answer is that in my release configuration it is set to `Don't Link`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> despite my app having nothing to do with these frameworks.

Is your `Link Behavior` in your release configuration set to `Don't Link`?

If so, the non-stripped `Xamarin.iOS.dll` references everything and will cause all kinds of privacy/entitlement issues just due to the fact that your app is linked to them but actually never uses them.

The default Release configuration used to be `Link Framework SDKs Only` (`-linksdk`) but in the recent releases that does not seem to be the case even though the documentation states that it is.

Change the behavior to `Link Framework SDKs Only`, create another archive and `ipa` and see if Apple likes that version ;-)