# Xamarin IOS - Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store, provisioning-profile, testflight

I got this mail when publish app to TestFlight:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file.

I use Microsoft visual studio for mac. In entitlement.plist Push Notification is disabled and in Developer Apple Account / App IDs / Push notification it's disabled too. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXE9j.png)
I don't want to use push notification. What I need to do to not get this mail ?

Comment: Is the `Link Behavior` in your release configuration set to `Don't Link`? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256973/4984832

Comment: It set to "Don't Link"

Comment: That is your problem,

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123/missing-push-notification-entitlement

Answer (score 2):

Open entitlments plist, go to Source and Modify aps-environment to development

Answer (score 0):

I wish to expand your understanding of this issue, iOS apps work in sandbox means each app have limited access to system resources, Entitlement requests additional capabilities like a push notification service.

[Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/provisioning/working-with-entitlements/)

if you want to use push notification, add this key **aps-environment** with value 
development for **development** mode or **production**  for production mode

if you dont want this capability just remove it.