# Xamarin Forms - IOS Distribution "SMS Fraud Extension"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

My app developed using Xamarin Forms has been rejected due to an extension called SMS Fraud Extension, but I have no idea what it is. The message I received from Apple is:

> Guideline 2.5.12 - Performance - Software Requirements   We noticed
>   that your app uses the SMS Fraud Extension to block or filter messages
>   from a list of phone numbers, but your app does not explain the
>   criteria for inclusion in the list.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to clearly explain the
>   criteria for the blocked and spam list included in your app.

How can I disable this extension? I am not using anything related to SMS in my app.

It has been developed using Visual Studio 2017.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the `Linker` turned on in your Release build configuration?

Comment: @SushiHangover It's selected 'Don’t Link' option

Comment: The linker needs to be set to at least `SDK` in order to strip the unused framework references from the `Xamarin.iOS.dll` (the default assembly contains references to all the iOS frameworks for development purposes) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256973/4984832